# Checking JSON response from browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to render a response in JSON and then, check the JSON document generated by Rails from the browser. I can't do it because a `TemplateNotFound` exception is raised. It's weird to me because, as it's seen, JSON is sample text and shouldn't need a template.

```
def who_bought
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @lastest_order = @product.orders.order(:updated).last

  if stale?(@lastest_order)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.atom
      format.xml { render :xml => @product.to_xml(:include => :orders)}
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone knows what is missing?

Comment: Which rails version are you using?

Comment: Hey nathanvda! Currently, I'm using Rails 4.0.0.

Comment: Are you sure that the condition `if stale?(@lastest_order)` passes? And what if it doesn't?

Comment: Hey Jacob K! I think so, but is quite weird because I have just replace `stale?(@lastest_order)` for `false`and it renders the atom response anyways.

Comment: Can we see the routes file?

Comment: Yes, of course. https://github.com/tehAnswer/RoR/blob/master/depot/config/routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

To get a JSON response, request type must be JSON. Append `.json` to the url. For e.g. `localhost:3000/posts.json` would return JSON data.

Comment: Hey Himesh! That's what I'm doing. It works well for `GET /products.json`, obviously is scaffolding code, but not for my own method (for example, `GET /products/2/who_bought.json`. At least, atom works.

Comment: That's really strange, haven't really come across any situation where JSON request gives template missing error!